# Alternatives to PHP

Tags: php

We are starting a project, which goal is to create new frontend interface to our product. Old version was created in PHP, very poorly written. We are choosing the language and frameworks that we want to use in new version.

Requirements:

1. New interface will be communicating with API. Application will not have it's own database.
2. We don't have a big team, 3 max programmers for entire project.
3. The main programmers are PHP veterans and knows some other technologies (Rails, C, C++, some Java) but not in professional level. But overall they are good and experienced programmers.

So:

1. We want to find a good alternative to PHP. I like Rails very much, but whole ActiveRecord model will be useless, when using application API.
2. Java needs a lot of configuration and someone who is expert in Java to properly run this project. Also, in Java there are a lot of big and complicated enterprise frameworks - not very good for 2-3 programmers team.
3. Python - I don't know Python and don't know good and experienced programmers who knows  PY - but it's not so complicated and big as Java and maybe in long period it's good alternative for PHP.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you have good programmers that know PHP, then use PHP. Your problem isn't really with the language, it's with badly written code - which can be written in any language. (Granted, PHP does make it a little easier for newbies to write bad code.)

There are plenty of frameworks for PHP that can help keep your code clean. Personally I prefer the simplicity of CodeIgniter, but read up on more advanced ones like CakePHP.

As for other languages, in my experience Java is completely unsuitable for a web language. ASP.net is a decent option but obviously relies on Microsoft technologies (Stack Overflow is built on ASP.net so it's clearly no slouch.) Python is pretty solid as far as I know - Google uses it extensively, too.

Comment: « *Java is completely unsuitable for a web language* »  I don't agree, especially when working on big projects. Web dev has to be more structured and it may take more time (tapestry, jsp, struts..). But maintenance and debugging are easier.